# how to create project files in sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

hi i am new in sbt i am following this tutorial 
http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Hello.html
i followed the same steps on the shell the program displays "hi"
i am confused i don't have these files in my hello folder

- Sources in src/main/scala or src/main/java
- Tests in src/test/scala or src/test/java
- Data files in src/main/resources or src/test/resources
- jars in lib

and also i dont't have the build.sbt file i am following this tutorial as it is i have only hw.scala file and a target folder
mt scala version is 2.11.1 and sbt version is sbt 0.13.5
am i doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create `build.sbt` and write appropriate lines into it. Same goes for mentioned directories -- stock sbt does not *create* files and folders for you, but it has to *recognize* them, once they're there.

Comment: do i have to create manually every time sbt does not create it ?? as in this tutorial

Comment: @user3801239 if you are going to use sbt alone, yes, you have to reproduce them for every new project. Having said this, you usually don't have to: e.g. Intellij IDEA will fill them for you, once you create new project, there is a [g8 tool](https://github.com/n8han/giter8) which spins new project from the template and so on.

Comment: That's kind of a bummer answer.  Maven allows you to generate files for support a Java project without having to have intimate knowledge of what goes into creating maven project file.  For node, you have npm that can get you started.  For other languages, their package management system typically has this.

For Scala, you have to have intimate knowledge of the build system and it's valid basic file format before you can create a hello world application?  To me, that seems pretty backwards.  I'd rather focus on scala app code than what a valid build.sbt file looks like.

Comment: @AndrewAllbright the thing is -- you can just write the `HelloWorld.scala` right in your top directory and have no sbt definitions at all. Check this https://gist.github.com/lazyval/f48d2ffb830562834191c545c341c53c out and run `sbt run` in it and you'll be surprized to know you can actually focus on scala and not the build definition.

Comment: @om-nom-nom Ah, that is indeed handy then!  I concede that since the build file is optional, it doesn't hinder initial development in the language.  Very neat!